# How to create tables in windows azure?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am new to windows azure.Can anyone please tell me the process of creating database and tables in windows azure and how to connect to that connection to application .we have windows azure account .please clarify my doubts.any of pdf books for deploying the rest wcf services in cloud let me know the links.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you even logged into the Windows Azure Portal?

Comment: I am successfully creating the database but how can i create or  configure theh tables in that database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the database server in the management portal. 1st thing you would do is manage the allowed IP Addresses which can access this server/database. Allow your local IP address there. After that you have 2 choices:

1. Use Sql Server Management Studio - It does not have the table editor and you would need to write T-SQL scripts manually.
2. Use Silverlight based database management utility - to access this, click on the Manage Url link as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: How to run sql server management studio scripts in that silverlight based management utility.Getting errors while running ?

Comment: Msg 40514, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
'Filegroup reference and partitioning scheme' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

Comment: Aah ... I see. There're some differences between SQL Server and SQL Azure and one of them is this "Filegroup". Please take a look at this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff394115.aspx for more details. One thing I would recommend is to create a script targeting SQL Azure from your existing database using SSMS. Take a look at this link for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee621790.aspx

Comment: Assuming you're deploying your WCF service as a "Cloud Service", take a look at this link which will guide you through the process: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/cloud-services/how-to-create-and-deploy-a-cloud-service/.

Comment: Thanks i am successfully deploying services in cloud .But can't able to migrate the sql server 2008 scripts in azure.newly cretaed tables are working .please tell me migration of database process.

Comment: i didn't find any advanced setting  option while generating scripts in sql server 2008 management studio.found only  set “Convert UDDTs to Base Types” option the below options i didnt found  Script for the database engine type” option as “SQL Database”, and set “Types of data to script” option as “Schema and data”.where to find those options?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have SQL Server 2008 Management Studio. What you could do is install SQL Server 2012 Management Studio. It does have these options.

Comment: Thanks i will install and try.any pdf books to get  more knowledge on this windows azure?.

Comment: Hi.Please tell me how to give image path in sqlazure table.actually i am creating one folder in iis in that saving images.but in cloud how to acheive this?

Answer (score 2):

It is May 2014 and that Silverlight online tool just is not really much better.

```
Best approach is to use SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio)  you can even use the free tools tool.   
Connect to your Azure with the portal supplied server url / port ... and then your username /password.
```

Say you scripted out an existing database tables and want to execute that script, you have much more freedom and control with SSMS than online.

For table creation note that a few caveats, One that is common is that not all of T-SQL is supported and a typical script from another database table(s) you end up needed to strip off the two "ON [PRIMARY]" parts of the create statement

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot have wizards for Adding/Editing tables, constraints or keys for  `Azure DB`, even if you have connected it through `MS SQL Server Management Studio`, you can use [**RazorSQL**](https://razorsql.com/) for this purpose. It gives you a feeling like you are playing with your azure DB in management studio, same as you do with your normal DBs